# Is it possible to click through a movable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click

I am working on some jQuery/JavaScript that makes it possible to drag a div around and simultaneously be able to manipulate other divs (specifically images) on the page. The movable div is basically a transparent rectangle that is meant to simulate a lens. The problem I am having is that I cannot figure out how to pass clicks through to the images below the movable div. I have read up on the pointer-events CSS property and tried setting that to none for the movable div, but that makes the movable div no longer movable. Is there a way for me to pass clicks through this movable div while keeping it movable?

EDIT: To all those asking for my current code, here is the JavaScript that I have so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').click(function(e) {
  $(document).unbind('keypress');
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 115) {
      $(e.target).css('width', '+=25').css('height', '+=25');
    };

    if ( event.which == 97) {
      $(e.target).css('width', '-=25').css('height', '-=25');
    };
  });
});

//code to drag the lens around with the mouse
$("#draggableLens").mousemove(function(e){

  var lensPositionX = e.pageX - 75;
  var lensPositionY = e.pageY - 75;

  $('.lens').css({top: lensPositionY, left: lensPositionX});

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: how you imaginate this ? you drag your lens and where the click will be ?

Comment: maybe if the movable `div` has a handler, for instance the easydrag plugin allows you to set a handler rather than dragging the whole `div` **[CHECK THIS](http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/07/14/easydrag-jquery-plugin/)**

Comment: I don't exactly understand how you can simultaneously drag and click, but you might be looking for something like this: moveableDiv.click(function(e){$(document.elementFromPoint(e.pagex, e.pagey)).click();})

Comment: Add relevant html, script to your question, can you show its screenshot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a demo that is proof of concept using `document.elementFromPoint` to locate the nearest image the moveable element is over. I used jQueryUI draggable to simplify event handling.

The trick with using `document.elementFromPoint` is you must hide the element you are dragging just long enough to look for other elements, or the draggging element is itself the closest element.

Adding an `active` class to the closest element allows clicking on the viewer to access the active element

Demo code uses `LI` tags instead of `IMG`

```
var $images = $('#list li');
timer = false;
$('#viewer').draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (!timer) {
            timer = true;
            var $self = $(this);
            /* use a timeout to throttle checking for the closest*/
            setTimeout(function() {
                /* must hide the viewer so it isn't returned as "elementFromPoint"*/
                $self.hide()
                var el = $(document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY));                    
                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                if ($el.is('li')) {
                    $el.addClass('active')
                }
                $self.show()
                timer = false;
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}).click(function() {
    if ($('.active').length) {
        msg = 'Clicked on: ' + $('.active').text();

    } else {
        msg = 'Click - No active image';
    }
    $('#log').html(msg + '<br>');

})
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/nfjjV/4/

`document.elementFromPoint` is not be supported in older browsers. You could also use jQuery `position` or `offset` methods to compare coordinates of elements with the current position of the viewer for full browser compatibility

Comment: Your post gave me an idea that ultimately solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: am curious what solution is. Problem was an interesting one